# A button to save currently reading thread to your "favourites", or "read threads"

Tags: support, bookmarks

It could become a very useful reference for anyone for a quick go through anytime.

Also, such lists from multiple users can be combined to make a sort of book of difficult/confusing questions that could turn out to be an equally important book to read when learning from websites which usually do not provide very in-depth information about a subject to speed-up things instead of reading bulky reference books. I don't mean to replace those reference books altogether, but yes, this can really speed-up things.

Comment: -1 just 4 tis.. we're not in chat or SMS here.

Answer (score 6):

You mean something like, say, this?

[image]

To view your favourites, click on your profile, the "Favourites" tab and you can sort by votes-newest-views-recent or added.

Comment: +1 for the implied sarcasm and the hand drawn circle :-)

Comment: @RoryAlsop, I wasn't *intending* to be sarcastic...honest...

Comment: @RoryAlsop good one...and sorry 4 not knowing such basic thing.

Comment: @tombull89 : dat was rude, but funny :)